# Increase quantity field when duplicate serial numbers entered

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm trying to create POS system using oracle apex like the one at supermarkets, my issue is when the user scan the same item twice I want the application to increase it's quantity by '1' not to duplicate the record in my database, so I have write the below code but it doesn't work the way I want and it keep duplicating the item record on database.

```
declare v_count number;

begin

select COUNT(*) co
into v_count
from POS_TRANS_DETAIL
where PTM_ID = :P21_MASTER_ID and serial_number = :P21_SERIAL_NUMBER ;

if v_count >= 1 then
    update POS_TRANS_DETAIL
    set QUANTITY = v_count +1
    where PTM_ID = :P21_MASTER_ID and serial_number = :P21_SERIAL_NUMBER ;
end if;
EXCEPTION 
WHEN no_data_found THEN 
    begin
    insert into POS_TRANS_DETAIL values (
    TRANS_DETAIL_ID.nextval,
    :P21_PTM_ID,
    :P21_SERIAL_NUMBER,
    :P21_COST_PRICE,
    :P21_QUANTITY,
);
end;

end;
```

The first statement is for getting any duplicate serial number in the same receipt number (PTM_ID) and to store number of duplicate record on `v_count`, using the if statement I'm making sure that `v_count` has a value and then applying the update for quantity column, and in the exception section I'm handling new item insertion when no row return from the select statement which mean that the item didn't added before for the same receipt

I'm placing this code on a dynamic action fired when the user add new item.

Comment: Not completely sure, but maybe a problem would be that the information is not yet commited. APEX does not automatically always commit all data until the page is submitted. So try just adding a COMMIT to the end(or after update and insert), and see if that might work

Comment: Thanks @TineO, I have tried to add commit after update and insert with same result nothing changed

Answer (score 3):

Rather than a drawn out procedure you just need a single statement: [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F). What you are attempting is the very reason for it existence. I believe it needs to be rapped in a procedure (block) in Apex (but I do not actually know Apex.)

```
begin 
merge into pos_trans_detail ptd
    using (select :p21_master_id  ptm_id
                , :p21_serial_number serial_number
                , :p21_cost_price   cost_price
                , :p21_quantity    quantity
             from dual
          ) parm
    on (    ptd.ptm_id = parm. ptm_id
        and ptd.serial_number = parm.serial_number
       ) 
 when found then 
      update set quantity = quantity + parm.quantity
 when not found 
      insert into pos_trans_detail ptd(id, ptm_id,serial_number,cost_price ,quantity 
      values ( trans_detail_id.nextval 
            , parm.ptm_id
            , parm.serial_number
            , parm.cost_price
            , parm.quantity
            ); 
end ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of issues in your code. See below my coments

My version would look like this:

**Update** ( With debug )

```
declare 
v_count number;
begin
 
apex_debug.enable ( p_level => 5 );

select COUNT(*) into v_count
from POS_TRANS_DETAIL
where PTM_ID = :P21_MASTER_ID and serial_number = :P21_SERIAL_NUMBER ;

apex_debug.message(p_message => 'Counter is '||v_count||'', p_level => 5) ;

if v_count >= 1 then
    update POS_TRANS_DETAIL
    set QUANTITY = v_count +1
    where PTM_ID = :P21_MASTER_ID and serial_number = :P21_SERIAL_NUMBER ;
else
    insert into POS_TRANS_DETAIL values (
    TRANS_DETAIL_ID.nextval,
    :P21_PTM_ID,
    :P21_SERIAL_NUMBER,
    :P21_COST_PRICE,
    :P21_QUANTITY,
);
end if;

commit -- Apex does not autocommit, it depends on the method this code is assigned to ( submit page, after submit, etc ). Better use commit always

exception when others then raise;
end;
```

Key points

- You are using `exception when no data found` to make an insert, but your code is doing select count, which is always found ( either 0 or some value ). So that part will never execute
- I guess you wanted to insert when there is 0 in the counter, therefore it goes into the else section of that if-else statement.
- Use `commit` if you are not sure your method does. Oracle Apex does autocommit if the method associated to this code is intended for it. For example, submit page. A good advice is always treat PLSQL code in Apex as if you would use it in Oracle DB directly. But use your common sense to use or not commit within your code in case you code is part of a compose process treated as a single transaction. Thanks to @Koen Lostrie for that remark!

Comment: Thanks for your reply @roberto, I have tried your idea with the if-else statement with no luck, item keeps inserted instead of updating `quantity`, and thanks for the `commit` advise I didn't faced any issue with apex so I think it autocommit.

Comment: @Roberto I don't agree with the "use always commit".  My advice is to let apex handle the commits. For example If there are 3 page processes then those 3 should probably be seen as a single transaction. If the 3rd one fails it will only rollback that 3rd one and you might have rogue data from process 1 and 2 - that is probably not what the developer intends ... Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @KoenLostrie, of course in that scenario it would not be advisable, but that is very kind of strange scenario, if you ask me. I never saw any APEX application with code in different page elements all being para of a single transaction. But, you are right, in your example, let Apex decide

Comment: @OmarZ.AL-Khatib, do you know how to use `apex_debug` ? It would be interesting to debug that code to see what the variable is getting. Keep in mind that if it does the insert is because the counter is always 0. I updated the post. Just run the app with debug enable and check what the counter is giving you. I assure you is 0. You can also check the values of the apex variables passed to the query